# How to encrypt/decrypt data using RSA OAEP SHA-256 in Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

How can I encrypt my string data with SHA-256 padding instead of the default SHA-1 padding in Crypto++? I have not been able to find any way to change what padding algorithm my encryption/decryption functions use. I have heard of some libraries having hard-coded padding schemes, but I hope that there is a way to modify the one used by Crypto++.

Here is my encryption method:

```cpp
string GUIMain::encryptData(const string data) {
    CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(*serverPublic);
    string cipher;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss1(data, true, new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, e, new CryptoPP::StringSink(cipher)));
    return cipher;
}
```

Here is my decryption method:

```cpp
string GUIMain::decryptData(const string cipher) {
    CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d(*privateKey);
    string recovered;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(cipher, true, new CryptoPP::PK_DecryptorFilter(*rng, d, new CryptoPP::StringSink(recovered)));
    return recovered;
}
```

The keys (`*serverPublic` and `*privateKey`) are object types `RSA::PublicKey` and `RSA::PrivateKey` respectively. `*rng` is an `AutoSeededRandomPool` object.

Is there any way I could add to/change these methods to work correctly? I am new to C++, so please explain solutions if possible.

Comment: As a new user you may be interested in the [Crypto++ wiki](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Main_Page) and the [Crypto++ manual](https://cryptopp.com/docs/ref/). The wiki is stuffed full of example code, like [RSA Cryptography](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography) and [RSA Encryption Schemes](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I encrypt my string data with SHA-256 padding instead of the default SHA-1 padding in Crypto++?

`RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor` and `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor` are typedefs:

```
$ grep RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor *.h
rsa.h:DOCUMENTED_TYPEDEF(RSAES<OAEP<SHA1> >::Encryptor, RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor);

$ grep RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor *.h
rsa.h:DOCUMENTED_TYPEDEF(RSAES<OAEP<SHA1> >::Decryptor, RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor);
```

You can use the following instead:

```
 RSAES<OAEP<SHA256> >
```

So your encryptor and decryptor would be:

```
 RSAES<OAEP<SHA256> >::Encryptor
 RSAES<OAEP<SHA256> >::Decryptor
```

Keep the extra space after the `>` for the template. It is needed on older versions of the C++ language. Otherwise, the compiler sees `>>` and thinks it is part of an extraction operator.

---

There are several typedefs like the ones you are using:

```
$ grep RSAES *.h
...
rsa.h:struct RSAES : public TF_ES<RSA, STANDARD>
rsa.h:/// \brief \ref RSAES<STANDARD> "RSAES<PKCS1v15>::Decryptor" typedef
rsa.h:DOCUMENTED_TYPEDEF(RSAES<PKCS1v15>::Decryptor, RSAES_PKCS1v15_Decryptor);
rsa.h:/// \brief \ref RSAES<STANDARD> "RSAES<PKCS1v15>::Encryptor" typedef
rsa.h:DOCUMENTED_TYPEDEF(RSAES<PKCS1v15>::Encryptor, RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor);
rsa.h:/// \brief \ref RSAES<STANDARD> "RSAES<OAEP<SHA1>>::Decryptor" typedef
rsa.h:DOCUMENTED_TYPEDEF(RSAES<OAEP<SHA1> >::Decryptor, RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor);
rsa.h:/// \brief \ref RSAES<STANDARD> "RSAES<OAEP<SHA1>>::Encryptor" typedef
rsa.h:DOCUMENTED_TYPEDEF(RSAES<OAEP<SHA1> >::Encryptor, RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor);
```

---

`DOCUMENTED_TYPEDEF` is a macro in `config_ns.h`. The macro helps generate better documentation when `make docs` is run.

A regular compile uses the following.

```
typedef RSAES<OAEP<SHA1> >::Encryptor RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor;
```

A documentation build uses the following. Inheritance works better when building documentation.

```
struct RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor : RSAES<OAEP<SHA1> >::Encryptor
{
};
```